# how to use autoPep8 extension with ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pep8, autopep8

I'm new to python extensions and after installing autopep8 and ran:

```
jupyter nbextension enable jupyter-autopep8-master/jupyter-autopep8
```

It returned:

```
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-autopep8-master/jupyter-autopep8...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X jupyter-autopep8-master/jupyter-autopep8
```

But I don't see any new button on ipynb interface for automatically format code into pep8. How could I use the extension in ipynb? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that autopep8 is installed and also install the extension from repo:

```
pip install autopep8
jupyter nbextension install https://github.com/kenkoooo/jupyter-autopep8/archive/master.zip --user
jupyter nbextension enable jupyter-autopep8-master/jupyter-autopep8
jupyter nbextension list
```

Depending your Jupyter setup, you may want to restart your Jupyter service:

`sudo service jupyter restart`

Comment: general recommendation: drop the 'sudo'